# I don't understand JSON and when I'm supposed to use it, care to explain?

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

I just started learning ASP.NET and I came across Web Services. I don't fully understand what purpose does JSON serves, when am I supposed to use it, and why is it better than XML. Care to explain please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536893/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-xml-and-json

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a text-based object serialization format that's more lightweight than XML. It directly integrates with JavaScript's object model. That's most of its advantages right there.

Comment: Thanks. In what situations does a web application call for that?

Comment: It is used primarily to transmit data between a server and web application, serving as an alternative to XML. This link would help you (http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/)

Answer (score 0):

You would primarily use JSON to send data between a web client and a web server, often times using WebServices. It serializes arrays and objects into human readable text and can easily be parsed by a computer. It is the ECMA 404 standard.

Here is an example of a JSON serialized class with some properties, with one of the properties being an array:

```
{firstname: 'Joe',  lastname: 'Smith', phonenumbers: ['555-555-5555','444-444-4444']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also JSON in many cases is more lightweight to work with than XML, due to it's simple format. I would, if you not already feel you are familiar with arrays, functions and objects in JavaScript- take a look at it. After that JSON will feel very familiar and easy to work with

Answer (score 0):

JSON is syntax for storing and exchanging text information - much like XML.
It's main advatages over XML are:

- is smaller and shorter than XML
- faster and easier to parse,
- quicker to read and write

from W3schools, JSON object could look like this:

```
var employees = [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
];
```

XML file could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees >
 <employee>
   <firstName>John</firstName>
   <lastName>Doe</lastName>
 </employee>
 <employee>
   <firstName>Anna</firstName>
   <lastName>Smith</lastName>
 </employee>
 <employee>
   <firstName>Peter</firstName>
   <lastName>Jones</lastName>
 </employee>
</employees >
```

From the above examples you should see it is much faster to read and write JSON object rather than XML, because it is much smaller and shorter.

When you want to do some data exchange between the server and web browser and dynamically load some data - for example from a database, JSON object is extremely handy:

```
function yourJavascriptfunction(sender){

   $.post("returndata.php", {
    UserID:sender.name
     })
    .success(function(data){    
     var returnedObject = JSON.parse(data);
     for(var i = 0; i < returnedObject.Data.length; i++){
        console.log(returnedObject.Data[i]["someRowInYourTable"]);
     }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert("Unable to retrieve data from the server, error code:" + errorThrown);
    });
 }
```

and your php file called returndata.php could return for example these data from your created database

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","yourDatabase") or die(mysql_error());
    $userID = $_POST['UserID'];

    $query1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid = $userID");

    $returnObject = new stdClass();
    $returnObject->Error = "Some error";
    $ObjectArray = array();
    $position = 0;

    while ($newrow = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
        $ObjectArray[$position] = $newrow;
        $position++;
    }

    $returnObject->Data = $ObjectArray;
    echo json_encode($returnObject);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed some differences...

**Advantages of XML:**

- Supports Comments
- Supports namespaces
- Supports schemas

**Advantages of JSON:**

- Smaller
- Natively supports null
- Native object support
- Native array support
- Provides scalar datatypes (strings are strings and numbers are numbers, etc.). Lacking with dates though.
- Simpler (but matter of opinion)

**Readability...** Some argue that XML is harder to read... I disagree. For hierarchical data, XML can shine. JSON can look like gibberish if you are not used it, especially if it's not formatted and indented. I think it's a draw in this case.